# Spectrum claims their router is required for static ip on their gigabit plan, is it true and why?

Tags: networking, router

We recently upgraded to Spectrum's gigabit none-dedicated business service(1gig down / 35 meg up) . I had a cisco router and we have since switced to pfSense running on a beefy server.

When they upgraded us, the tech came out and put their own router between our router and the modem. They said this was required for the new service because we have a static ip. I thought that was bizzare given our equipment and the fact that I still setup the static ip in our router but he called his support to confirm it was required, and I let him do it thinking it was surely going not going to cooperate with our vpn setup and there must be some kind of nat involved but to my shock it worked.

What's going on here? Is anyone familar with their specific setup that makes their router required . Is there any settings I could use in pfSense that would get around that requirement?

I did try connecting my pfsense router direct to the modem. If I put the static ip setup in it won't connect, I did try spoofing the mac in case that was part of it.

If I hook up my router to their router the static ip setup works correctly, and if I do not hook up my router but hook any other machine direct to their router it is assigned a local dhcp address and externally the static ip still works. So their router still works like a normal router when hooked to something other than another router, but passes through the ip fine if connected to another router.

Comment: Can you tell us specific information about the Spectrum hardware.  You are likely fiber to the home, if so that changes, what can and cannot be done.  You won't be able to connect your own hardware unless you provision your hardware which requires Spectrum.

Comment: Wondering the same thing.  We were just forced to have a technician come to our facility to install an additional router in order to enable a static IP.  Were you able to get your router to work with the modem or are you still using the spectrum router?

Comment: @OsmaanShah was not able to get a bare router to connect direct to their modem without going through their router.